# Applying different styles to items created with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wish to apply different stylings to buttons created using ng-repeat. I want `b.color` to return a value from the btnValues object but it does not return the value. Is this possible or is there another way of doing it?

```
<a href=""
class="modal-button {{b.color}}"
data-ng-repeat="b in btnValues"
data-ng-click="close(b.value)">{{ b.name }}</a>
```

Comment: try ng-class or ng-style

Comment: This should work fine. What does the generated HTML look like? What is displayed when you add `{{ b.color }}` inside the link?

Comment: It seems as if `b.color` is not returning any value - I added it to the generated HTML.  Thank you, I should have checked this first

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<a href=""
class="modal-button" ng-class="b.color"
data-ng-repeat="b in btnValues"
data-ng-click="close(b.value)">{{ b.name }}</a>
```

If it doesn't work check the value of `{{b.color}}` to be sure that is valued.

Then check if the class with name corresponding to `{{b.color}}` is present in the css.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ng-class or ng-style :

```
<a href=""
class="modal-button" ng-style="{ color: b.color }"
data-ng-repeat="b in btnValues"
data-ng-click="close(b.value)">{{ b.name }}</a>
```

or

```
<a href=""
class="modal-button" ng-class="b.color"
data-ng-repeat="b in btnValues"
data-ng-click="close(b.value)">{{ b.name }}</a>
```